# Get indices of rows whose elements equal x at all columns indicated by a vector, in R

Tags: r, matrix

Let us have a matrix `M`, e.g.

```
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   15    0    0    9
[2,]    0    1    8   24
[3,]    4    0    0    0
[4,]    3    2    0    0
[5,]    0    0   56    0
```

a vector of its column indices `ind`, e.g.

```
> ind=c(2,4)
> ind
[1] 2 4
```

and a value `x`, e.g. `x=0`.

**How to get the indices of rows of matrix `M`, whose elements at all columns indicated by `ind` are equal to `x`**?

The following code returns proper row indices:

```
> which(M[,2]==0 & M[,4]==0)
[1] 3 5
```

but I need a solution that will use a vector `ind`, possibly very long. I tried:

```
> which(M[,ind]==0)
[1]  1  3  5  8  9 10
```

but instead I got the entries which have zeros in either of the columns indicated by `ind`, not in all of them at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
rowSums(M[, ind] == 0) == length(ind)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Let's break the code down step-by-step:

- `M[, ind] == 0` - get a logical matrix showing where `M[, ind]` is zero
- `rowSums(.)` - determine how many TRUE values are in each row
- `. == length(ind)` - compare it to the number of columns used

And if you need the numeric indices, wrap it in `which()`.

```
which(rowSums(M[, ind] == 0) == length(ind))
# [1] 3 5
```

**Data:**

```
M <- structure(c(15L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 
0L, 0L, 56L, 9L, 24L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(5L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")))
ind <- c(2, 4)
```

Comment: A slight improvement is needed, so that the solution works for the case `ind` vector is of length 1: `which(rowSums(M[, ind, drop=FALSE] == 0) == length(ind))`

Answer (score 3):

If ind is supposed to be a vector, then you should reference its elements, and not the whole thing. For example:

```
ind = c(2,4)

x = 0

M = the matrix

which(M[,ind[1]] == x & M[,ind[2]] == x)
```

This answer assumes that you know *how many* columns are to be searched ahead of time.

Comment: Thanks, it is an improvement, however in my case I don't know anything about M, ind or x beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

We can also negate with `rowSums` and get the index

```
which(!rowSums(M[, ind]!=0))
#[1] 3 5
```

---

If we break down the steps

```
rowSums(M[, ind]!=0)
#[1] 1 2 0 1 0
```

the 3rd and 4th elements are the only one which doesn't have any non zero values, so the `rowSums` return 0 for it.  Negating the output returns TRUE for 0 and FALSE for all others

```
!rowSums(M[, ind]!=0)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Now, wrapping with `which` returns the index of TRUE elements.